# How do I change the "Last-Modified" time format from the curl-head standard output?

Tags: command-line, curl, date

The following command can get the modification time of the remote file, how to modify the output time format?

```
# curl -sI https://sgp-ping.vultr.com/vultr.com.100MB.bin | grep Last-Modified | cut -c16-
Mon, 29 Apr 2019 20:22:54 GMT
```

I want to convert to `Y-m-d H:i:s` time format. any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pipe it to `date` command and use its formatting controls to format as you expect like:

```
... |date -f- '+%Y-%m-%d %T'
```

see more formatting controls in [`man date`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/date.1.html)